# Splitlines to get two splitted lines only

Tags: python, string, split

I have a long piece of text, which I want to divide into a list of paragraphs. I have been unable to find a working package, so I am writing a heuristic myself.

As a start, I want to split the text in all places with two linebreaks. So that the text below:

```
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse tortor neque, tempor condimentum erat eget, faucibus tristique quam. Praesent hendrerit, mi non finibus iaculis, justo lacus pharetra purus, vitae bibendum lectus erat sit amet risus. Integer porta, risus id accumsan accumsan, lacus augue finibus orci, eu interdum sapien odio at enim. Vestibulum eget libero nisl. Donec accumsan justo a sem semper vehicular. 

Etiam convallis sodales felis quis iaculis. Aenean eget rhoncus libero, non iaculis leo. Pellentesque dictum mauris libero, a feugiat elit mollis facilisis. Nulla facilisi. Aliquam dictum lorem vitae nisl suscipit faucibus. Suspendisse at rhoncus est, vitae sagittis metus. Etiam massa lacus, gravida ut elit sit amet, sagittis feugiat enim. Nullam dictum pretium mi ac rutrum. Fusce ornare sollicitudin augue, dignissim bibendum ante cursus non. 

Sed et urna ac nibh molestie venenatis non at eros. Suspendisse eget enim ornare turpis gravida finibus. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Quisque hendrerit eros eros, nec euismod erat maximus quis. Donec fringilla nibh id ligula porta lacinia. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Cras sit amet auctor augue. 
Aenean porttitor cursus tempor. Ut rutrum feugiat purus, ac tincidunt nisl pharetra in. Nunc nunc libero, placerat eu tempus et, sagittis volutpat libero. Maecenas sit amet arcu sed felis consectetur dapibus."
```

Would be split as follows (one line break only is considered the same paragraph):

```
["Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse tortor neque, tempor condimentum erat eget, faucibus tristique quam. Praesent hendrerit, mi non finibus iaculis, justo lacus pharetra purus, vitae bibendum lectus erat sit amet risus. Integer porta, risus id accumsan accumsan, lacus augue finibus orci, eu interdum sapien odio at enim. Vestibulum eget libero nisl. Donec accumsan justo a sem semper vehicular.",
"Etiam convallis sodales felis quis iaculis. Aenean eget rhoncus libero, non iaculis leo. Pellentesque dictum mauris libero, a feugiat elit mollis facilisis. Nulla facilisi. Aliquam dictum lorem vitae nisl suscipit faucibus. Suspendisse at rhoncus est, vitae sagittis metus. Etiam massa lacus, gravida ut elit sit amet, sagittis feugiat enim. Nullam dictum pretium mi ac rutrum. Fusce ornare sollicitudin augue, dignissim bibendum ante cursus non.",
"Sed et urna ac nibh molestie venenatis non at eros. Suspendisse eget enim ornare turpis gravida finibus. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Quisque hendrerit eros eros, nec euismod erat maximus quis. Donec fringilla nibh id ligula porta lacinia. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Cras sit amet auctor augue. 
    Aenean porttitor cursus tempor. Ut rutrum feugiat purus, ac tincidunt nisl pharetra in. Nunc nunc libero, placerat eu tempus et, sagittis volutpat libero. Maecenas sit amet arcu sed felis consectetur dapibus."]
```

How can I do this? (packages to use for this task are also welcome).

Comment: This question needs a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/). Please see [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html). Always provide a complete [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example").

Comment: What part of the self contained answer did I not satisfy @itprorh66?. I am showing to you the data input that I have, the desired outcome and describe my rationale.

Comment: The part that includes "It is important to ensure that the code given to others can be 'copied, pasted, compiled, run' so that they can help quickly and with a minimum of fuss."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

note : i saved your text in a textfile  as b.txt

```
enter code here

a = open("b.txt","r")
read_a = a.read()
a.close()
c =read_a.split("\n\n")
print(len(c))
print(c)
```